# pass a string with double and single quotes as parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me why this value from the database wont pass as a parameter

The value from the database has single and double quotes which i escaped using mysql_escape_string() before adding to the database.

```
<?php   
   $sample = "This is a test's \"output\".";
?>
<button onclick='myFunction(<?php echo addslashes($sample);?>)'></button>
<script>
 function myFunction(val){ 
    alert(val);
 }
</script>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: @CertainPerformance but php has: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode($s, JSON_HEX_TAG+JSON_HEX_APOS+JSON_HEX_QUOT)`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this way. Hope it will work.

```
<?php
    $sample = "This is a test's \"output\".";
    $sample = json_encode($sample);
?>
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo htmlentities($sample); ?>)">Button</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(val){
        alert(val);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 encode. You encode it in php, it wont have any quotes, and you can decode it in javascript, ie

```
<?php   
   $sample = "This is a test's \"output\".";
   echo base64_encode($sample);// VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QncyAib3V0cHV0Ii4=
?>
```

then

```
console.log(atob("VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QncyAib3V0cHV0Ii4=")); // This is a test's "output".
```

so just:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(atob(<?php echo base64_encode($sample); ?>))">Button</button>
```

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php